# What's the fastest way to get Adamantite ore in Terraria?

Tags: terraria-console

Ok, so me and my friends are going to do an event where we spawn every boss/event we can and see how long we live. Here's my problem I need Adamantite to summon Ocram. I've checked and my world has been blessed with Adamantite, but I can't find any. Where do I find it and what's the fastest and most efficient way to obtain Adamantite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way I've found to find Adamantite (and indeed, any of the new ores) is to go down to hell and fly/grapple along the roof with a light source. This way you'll be able to see a little ways into the roof to identify ores.

Comment: What color is it on the minimap?

Comment: It's been a while, but I want to say it's sort of reddish.

Comment: It's certainly red on the PC version so I wouldn't expect it to be any different on the console version.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, i say the best way is by making a hellevator, and once your about to fall into hell, build up 8 blocks and use a mining potion. Then, just dig left and right and you can see \ collect all the ores. I currently have 178 adamantite ore from this method

Comment: I also want to say you need a mythrill pick\drill or better if you want to collect adamantite, and a cobalt pick\drill to collect mythrill, and you can only craft a mythrill pick with a mythrill anvil

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have the same idea, try building a hellevator before you spawn in the ores and when you go down they will be lots of ores. I found that they mostly spawn at the top of hell under the jungle.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can find 2x2 patches at the bottom of the jungle biome underground. I've been looking all day and I've gotten 64 Adamantite ores from this method.

Answer (score 0):

Just look harder, mine more. I haven't done anything special other than second time mining and I've found titanium ore all over the place, mostly down pretty low close to hell but I've also found it closer to the surface. I currently have made everything you can with titanium and have a surplus of almost 900 titanium ore.

Answer (score 0):

I got 76 bars of it from the hellavator therefore I would really recommend using that option by fr in about 1 hour

Answer (score -1):

I recommend fishing with crate potion and alot of bait

Answer (score -1):

I usually find adamantite ore deep close to hell but in the jungle where all the lava is. From this I found chunks of adamantite ore I currently have 22 bars.

They can also be found in random caves but really deep but I recommend checking in the jungle because that's where I found most of my 22 bars.

But an hellevator is also a good idea especially under where the jungle is.

Answer (score -2):

I have found it easy to get Adamandite just by looking in random caves.

It took me about 20/30 minutes to get 30 Adamandite. Plus its fun, and I also found 13 Functionable Statues

Answer (score -3):

The easy way i found is strip mining down and once i find adamtite i keep mining that direction.